# How to Change URL parameter formats

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

when I pass parameters through `url` I want to change the format of them.

Is that possible?

```
http://localhost:51406/home/Booking?Rooms=1&Destination={  "name": "Mumbai, India",  "code": "BOM"}&DepartureDate=12/18/2017&ReturnDate=12/19/2017&Adults1=1&Children1=0&C1Age1=0&C1Age2=0&C1Age3=0&C1Age4=0&Adults2=0&Children2=0&C2Age1=0&C2Age2=0&C2Age3=0&C2Age4=0&Adults3=0&Children3=0&C3Age1=0&C3Age2=0&C3Age3=0&C3Age4=0
```

I want to change this like this

```
http://***/home/Booking?Rooms=1&Destination=%22Mumbai,%20India(BOM)%22&DepartureDate=12/18/2017&ReturnDate=12/21/2017&Adults1=1&Children1=0&C1Age1=0&C1Age2=0&C1Age3=0&C1Age4=0&Adults2=0&Children2=0&C2Age1=0&C2Age2=0&C2Age3=0&C2Age4=0&Adults3=0&Children3=0&C3Age1=0&C3Age2=0&C3Age3=0&C3Age4=0
```

the destination should change like second one

this is the searchcontroller.js

```
app.factory("States", function () {
    var states = [ { 'name' : 'Ansan, South Korea', 'code': 'A1N' },
                   { 'name' : 'Asan, South Korea', 'code': 'A1S' },
                   { 'name' : 'Mumbai, India', 'code': 'BOM' },
                   { 'name' : 'Atascadero - CA, United States', 'code': 'AA1' },
                   { 'name' : 'London, United Kingdom', 'code': 'LON' },
                   { 'name' : 'Arlon, Belgium', 'code': 'AAO' } ] 
    return states; 
});
```

this is the view part code

```
   <input name="states" id="city"
          style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 109px; font-size: 14px" 
          type="text" placeholder="Any worldwide city or airport"
          ng-model="selectedNumberNonEditable" allow-custom="false"
          typeahead="state as state.name + ' (' + state.code + ')' for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
          class="form-control" required>
```

---

### ADDED from comment

```
<a id="sbutton" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
   style="background-color: #E28F13; font-size: 14px"
   ng-href="@Url.Action("Booking", "home")?Rooms={{rooms}}
            &Destination={{selectedNumberNonEdita‌​ble|json}}
            &Departure‌​Date={{departuredate‌​}}"
   onclick="validate(event);"> Search </a>
```

Comment: Seems like the question is incomplete. Missing how you are using the state value and how you are passing to URL

Comment: <a id="sbutton" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background-color: #E28F13; font-size: 14px" ng-href="@Url.Action("Booking", "home")?Rooms={{rooms}}&Destination={{selectedNumberNonEditable|json}}&DepartureDate={{departuredate}}" onclick="validate(event);"> Search </a>

Comment: Use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to [percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Your need to use [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)

```js
var param = 'Destination={  "name": "Mumbai, India",  "code": "BOM"}';

var encodedParam = encodeURI(param );
console.log(encodedParam );
```

**Or**

Are you looking something like this

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

var url = 'http://localhost:51406/home/Booking?Rooms=1&Destination={  "name": "Mumbai, India",  "code": "BOM"}&DepartureDate=12/18/2017&ReturnDate=12/19/2017&Adults1=1&Children1=0&C1Age1=0&C1Age2=0&C1Age3=0&C1Age4=0&Adults2=0&Children2=0&C2Age1=0&C2Age2=0&C2Age3=0&C2Age4=0&Adults3=0&Children3=0&C3Age1=0&C3Age2=0&C3Age3=0&C3Age4=0';

var destination = JSON.parse(getParameterByName("Destination", url));
var newDestination = destination.name + "(" + destination.code + ")";

console.log(newDestination);
```

Comment: this is the searchcontroller.js part

Comment: app.factory("States", function () {
    var states = [
      { 'name' : 'Ansan, South Korea', 'code': 'A1N' },
      { 'name' : 'Asan, South Korea', 'code': 'A1S' },
      { 'name' : 'Mumbai, India', 'code': 'BOM' },
      { 'name' : 'Atascadero - CA, United States', 'code': 'AA1' },
      { 'name' : 'London, United Kingdom', 'code': 'LON' },
      { 'name' : 'Arlon, Belgium', 'code': 'AAO' }
    ]

     return states;
});

Comment: and this is the view coding part

Comment: <input name="states" id="city" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 109px; font-size: 14px" type="text" placeholder="Any worldwide city or airport" ng-model="selectedNumberNonEditable" allow-custom="false" typeahead="state as state.name + ' (' + state.code + ')' for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" required>

Comment: @harsharachith Please update these details in the question, someone might be able to help. Are you using angular?

Comment: yes...see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772109/how-to-search-a-airport-through-iata-codes-not-by-the-names